# what is encoding in [NSString stringWithCString: variable encoding:1]; or stringWithUTF8String

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstring

What does encoding:1 mean and what other values can be passed?
Please clarify arguments meaning, thanks.

```
 - (void)enterInfo {
    NSLog(@"What is the first name?");
    char cstring[40];
    scanf("%s", cstring);

    firstName = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:1];
}

- (void)printInfo {
   NSLog(@"First name: %@", firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`1` is `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and should not be passed as `1` but like:

```
firstName = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

You can find the full list of encoding in the [`NSString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings)